# How to create swap file / use swap space?

Tags: system-installation, swap

I noticed something called "[swap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)" while researching. I know it's supposed to be upto twice the amount of RAM, but I can't seem to change it myself (if needed).

I would like to know if when I installed Ubuntu, the installation made the swap file for me, or do I need to create one?

Can someone give me some clarifying advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Ubuntu 15.04 create a swap partition with the default installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678622/will-ubuntu-15-04-create-a-swap-partition-with-the-default-installation)

Comment: @karel: what does swap partitions have to do with this question? This question is about swapfiles.

Comment: This Duplicated question is older that the question it duplicates, this does not seem possible.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Duplicate questions are not decided only by the age of the post or by the number of votes  it received. The lower quality question removes the higher quality question is satisfying to its bad author but wrong for Ubuntu users generally. The author of this question hasn't visited Ask Ubuntu for 7 years. The correct standard to apply to this question is whether it is of any use to current Ask Ubuntu users as anything but a signpost pointing to the current duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

The swap space is a partition that ubuntu uses as something like virtual memory. Yes, it's created by ubuntu when you install it.

To change its size you need to use gparted to add space to it.

I don't know if it's a good idea to change the size of the swap.