# Will Ubuntu 15.04 create a swap partition with the default installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 15.04, swap

I am going to install a fresh Ubuntu 15.04 on a Lenovo X1 Carbon. I plan to select the default *Erase disk and install Ubuntu* option and tick both *Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security* and *Use LVM...* options.

Last time I installed a 14.04 like this, there was no swap partition created automatically. It's a pain to add it later. Will 15.04 do that out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Ubuntu always creates a swap partition if you choose automatic install.

And it is not pain to add a swap partition. It is quite easy to do.

Comment: Is that the one called `ubuntu--vg-swap_1`? It says `[SWAP]` as _MOUNTPOINT_ in `lsblk`. But the 14.04 I talked about above (which I upgraded to 15.04 when that came out) also has that partition, but no mountpoint.

Comment: There is no mount point for a swap partition.

Comment: Ok, `swapon -s` says there is `/dev/dm-2` with 8GB. :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

NO.
ubuntu 15.04 doesn't create a swap partition automatically.
But you'll get  option to create swap space during installation. 
You can use this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516996/what-swapfile-size-to-make-i-have-4gb-ram) to estimate how much swap you need depending on how much RAM you have.